# Sencha Application deployment on ios using Linux platform?

Tags: ios, cordova, cross-platform, sencha-touch-2.1

I have created a Sencha Touch Application. I have successfully deployed the application  to Android using Cordova. Now I have to deploy the application for ios platform. But the problem is that I am using Linux platform and right now I dont have a Mac. Also, the application which I am building is only for demo purpose which will be only used in our company. It will not be published on Apple Store. So is it possible to deploy sencha app to ios without using mac?. If yes, please suggest some link/tutorial or give some steps for deploying the app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No you will need a Mac, since you need to iPhone SDK to deploy an app. 
Even if you are just building a demo you will need a paid iPhone developers account to register you test devices.